# Columns names issues using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty new to python.
I am trying to  import the SMSSpam Collection Data using pandas read_csv module.
I
The import went went. 
But as the file does not have header I tried to include  columns names(variables names : "status" and "message" and ended up with empty file.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file_loc="C:\Users\User\Documents\JP\SMSCollection.txt"
df=pd.read_csv(file_loc,sep='\t')
```

The above code works well I got the  I got the 5571 rows x 2 columns].
But when I add columns using the following line of code

```
df.columns=["status","message"]
```

I ended up with an empty df
Any help on this ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to rename existing columns in the dataframe or add new columns to the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the column names at read time:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file_loc,sep='\t',header=None,names=["status","message"])
```